# Save audio file KIVY, PYTHON

Tags: python, audio, kivy

What I am trying to do is, save each recorded file with a different filename(Myaudio1,2,3). Currently this code saves the audio as MYAUDIO.3gp, replacing the old file.

```
class MyRecorder:
def __init__(self):
    '''Recorder object To access Android Hardware'''
    self.MediaRecorder = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder')
    self.AudioSource = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder$AudioSource')
    self.OutputFormat = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder$OutputFormat')
    self.AudioEncoder = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder$AudioEncoder')

    # create out recorder
    self.mRecorder = self.MediaRecorder()
    self.mRecorder.setAudioSource(self.AudioSource.MIC)
    self.mRecorder.setOutputFormat(self.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)
    self.mRecorder.setOutputFile('/sdcard/MYAUDIO.3gp')
    self.mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(self.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)
    self.mRecorder.prepare()
```

I don't remember where I found the full code but if you need it, let me know. Thank you

Comment: You should give audio file name unique every time, so you can use current timestamp as file name. so it will different each time,

Comment: I'm new to kivy/python... how do I use a timestamp? @LovekushVishwakarma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use datetime for this.

```
from datetime import datetime

d = datetime.now()
d = d.strftime("%d_%m_%Y_%H%M%S")

self.mRecorder.setOutputFile('/sdcard/MYAUDIO_{}.3gp'.format(d))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is perfect!!

Comment: please check [this] out if you can help(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322814/display-and-play-audio-files). Thanks in advance!