# Display and play audio files

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to python, and I'm trying to build a simple recording program. With the some help from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271126/save-audio-file-kivy-python/42279456?noredirect=1#comment71736937_42279456), I was able to add a timestamp for each recorded file

EDIT:

I did some research and decided on displaying the files with filechooser... this still does not work

```
def openfiles(self, *args):

    satter2 = BoxLayout(pos= (629, 950), size_hint= (.1,.1))
    self.fclv = FileChooserListView(path= '/sdcard/', filters= [‘*.3gp’])
    self.fclv.bind(on_selection= self.pressed(fclv.selection)
    scatter.add_widget(self.fclv)

    self.add_widget(satter2)


def pressed(self, filename):
     #with open(os.path.join(path, filename[0])) 


    if self.soundf is None:
        self.soundf = SoundLoader.load(self.path)
    if self.soundf.status != 'stop':
        self.soundf.stop()
    self.soundf.loop = False
    self.soundf.play()
```

Comment: So what is the questin exactly?

Comment: how do I display the list of saved audio? or play it

Comment: have you tried ListView?

Comment: I see you get downvoted. So I will try to help you a bit here. The easiest way to get answers on SO, is firstly, ask a specific question about a specific problem that is stopping your project. Secondly, show that you have actually tried something. Hope you dont take this as offence, but as a tip.

Comment: Thank you I will and I will also post my attempt to display the audio in a scrollview

Comment: I made an edit to my question

Comment: What ectsactly does not work? Does it not show the list?

Comment: No it doesn't show the list, but it opens the boxlayout. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how to show all `3gp` files in your current directory.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserListView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class MyLayout(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyLayout,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.fclv = FileChooserListView(path= '.', filters= ['*.3gp'])
        self.add_widget(self.fclv)


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()


MyApp().run()
```

Result is:

[image: Files in a ListView]

Comment: Thank you, I ended up putting it in a screen manager. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @RashIsh you are wellcome